# How do I make my search input box shrink transition after clicking off of it?

Tags: html, css

First, let me explain what my search input thing currently does:

1. The search box width is set to 150 px.
2. I hover over the search box. The css3 transitions smoothly the width linearly to 250 px.
3. I hover off of the search box. The search box jumps back to its original 150px length. (this is the problem, I want it to shrink
   back to 150px smoothly with css transitions)
4. I click on the search box. It transitions smoothly back to 250px.
5. I click off of the search box.  The box instantly jumps back to 150px (again, the problem, but for clicking off instead)

I want the search input to act like the search on stackoverflow when I click off or hover off. Try clicking on the search input above this question. Then click off. Both transitions are smooth either way. I just want this to work for both clicking and hovering off of the input.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/tbsy5f19/1/) is a working example of the code below in jsfiddle.

Here is the same code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>Example</title>
    
    <style type="text/css">
          .search-input {
          width: 150px;
          height: 30px;
          padding: 0 20px;
          border: 1px solid grey;
          border-radius:10px;
          border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
          border-top-right-radius: 0px;
          color: black;
          -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
          text-overflow: ellipsis;
          background: white;
        }
    
        .search-input:hover {
          outline: none;
          opacity:0.99;
          cursor: pointer;
          box-shadow:5px 1px 5px 9px #EBEBEB inset; 
          width: 250px;
          -webkit-transition: width 400ms;
          -moz-transition: width 400ms;
          -o-transition: width 400ms;
          transition: width 400ms;
        }
    
        .search-input:focus {
          width: 250px;
          -webkit-transition: width 400ms;
          -moz-transition: width 400ms;
          -o-transition: width 400ms;
          transition: width 400ms;
        }
    
        input:focus {
          outline: none;
        }
    
        body {
          background: darkgrey;
        }
    
        #search-icon {
          padding-top: 4px;
          height: 20px;
        }
    
        #search-btn {
          margin-left: -4px;
          height: 31px;
          width: 30px;
          border: none;
          border-radius: 7px;
          border-top-left-radius: 0px;
          border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
          background-color: grey;
        }
    
        #search-btn:hover{
          outline: none;
          cursor: pointer;
          box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #A6A6A6;
        }
    </style>
    
    
    </head>
    <body>
    
            
      <img id="search-icon" src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/132068/isolated/preview/f9bb81e576c1a361c61a8c08945b2c48-search-icon-by-vexels.png">
      <input class="search-input" type="text" placeholder="Search..." />
      <input type="submit" value="Go" id="search-btn" />
    
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply your `transition` to the base `.search-input` element, not just the `:hover` and `:focus` states so that the transition happens when you hover/focus off, too.

```css
.search-input {
  width: 150px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
  border-top-right-radius: 0px;
  color: black;
  -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  background: white;
  -webkit-transition: width 400ms;
  -moz-transition: width 400ms;
  -o-transition: width 400ms;
  transition: width 400ms;
}

.search-input:hover {
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.99;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 5px 1px 5px 9px #EBEBEB inset;
  width: 250px;
}

.search-input:focus {
  width: 250px;
}

input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

body {
  background: darkgrey;
}

#search-icon {
  padding-top: 4px;
  height: 20px;
}

#search-btn {
  margin-left: -4px;
  height: 31px;
  width: 30px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 7px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
  background-color: grey;
}

#search-btn:hover {
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #A6A6A6;
}
```

```html
<body>


  <img id="search-icon" src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/132068/isolated/preview/f9bb81e576c1a361c61a8c08945b2c48-search-icon-by-vexels.png">
  <input class="search-input" type="text" placeholder="Search..." />
  <input type="submit" value="Go" id="search-btn" />


</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the transition related CSS code in the normal block of the HTML element, not the hover and focus blocks of the HTML element. So for the `.search-input` class you'd place the transition code in the normal block while leaving it out of `.search-input:hover` and `.search-input:focus`.

```
.search-input {
    width: 150px;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    border-radius:10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
    border-top-right-radius: 0px;
    color: black;
    -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    background: white;
    -webkit-transition: width 400ms;
    -moz-transition: width 400ms;
    -o-transition: width 400ms;
    transition: width 400ms;
}

.search-input:hover {
    outline: none;
    opacity:0.99;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow:5px 1px 5px 9px #EBEBEB inset; 
    width: 250px;
}

.search-input:focus {
    width: 250px;
}
```